# Apache commons base64 decode and Sun base64 decode

Tags: java, base64

```
byte[] commonsDecode = Base64.decodeBase64(data);
debug("The data is " + commonsDecode.length + " bytes long for the apache commons base64 decoder.");
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] sunDecode = decoder.decodeBuffer(data);
Log.debug("The data is " + sunDecode.length + " bytes long for the SUN base64 decoder.");
```

Please explain to me why these two method calls would produce different length for the resulting byte arrays. I initially thought it might have to do with character encodings but if so I don't understand all of the issues properly. The above code was executed on the same system and in the same application, in the order shown above. So the default character encoding on that system would be the same.

**The input (test) data:**
The below is a System.out.println of the Java String.

```
qFkIQgDq jk3ScHpqx8BPVS97YE4pP/nBl5Qw7mBnpSGqNqSdGIkLPVod0pBl Uz7NgpizHDicGzNCaauefAdwGklpPr0YdwCu4wRkwyAuvtDmL0BYASOn2tDw72LMz5FChtSa0CoCBQ2ARsFG2GdflnIWsUuBQapX73ZBMiqqm  ZCOnMRv9Ol8zT1TECddlKZMYAvmjANgq0sBPyUMF7co XY9BYAjV3L/cA8CGQpXGdrsAgjPKMhzk4hh1GAoQ1soX2Dva8p3erPJ4sy2Vcb6lS1Hap9FR0AZFawbJ10FFSTg10wxc24539kYA6xxq/TFqkhaEoSyTqjXjvo1SA==
```

Apache commons decoder says it's 252 length byte array.
Java Sun decoder says 256.

Comment: Note that the Sun base64 decoder you're using is most likely not a published class/ official API and thus it's discouraged to use it. An official base 64 decoder will be add in Java SE 8: http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html

Comment: Don't use the `sun.misc` or `com.sun` classes. They are undocumented and can change from Java release to Java release. As there is no documentation, how do you know what it is supposed to do anyway?

Comment: Can you convert the byte-arrays to the data format you need in both cases?

Comment: @Codo That doesn't answer the question. I used this as a test case not as production code. Both decoders should ideally output the same length byte array but they do not. Why not?

Comment: @Puce a byte[] is the format I need. I base64 encoded the values for transmission, nothing more.

Comment: @KyleM It wasn't an answer, it was a comment saying: you shouldn't need to care unless you're working on the OpenJDK project.

Comment: But what are you doing with the byte-array after decoding it? At some point some application will use this data, right? Can that application use the data produced by both decoders?

Comment: @KyleM: Show us your input data and the resulting lengths you get from the two decoders. Then I'll tell you which one is correct.

Comment: @Codo Done, see edit to the original post.

Comment: @Puce I shouldn't care that two different decoders produce different outputs? How am I supposed to ascertain why one of them is wrong? The original input was 256 bytes long. So the decoded output should be as well. But apache commons decoder gets 252 bytes. 

Why would apache commons decoder contain a bug in v1.5? It indicates that I don't understand something, hence why I posted this question.

Comment: @KyleM Fair enough, but as I understand this issue, the question should be: "Why does the Apache Commons Base64 decoder return an array of length 252, when the original input had a length of 256?" Of course you can play around with the Sun decoder to compare results, but we just wanted you to know that it's strongly discouraged to use unpublished classes in production code afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decoded data is not valid Base64 data.

Valid Base64 data can contain whitespace. Usually, it has a newline every 72 characters. However, your data contains spaces in random places. If they are removed (as every Base64 decoder is supposed to do), 339 characters remain. Yet, valid Base64 data has to be a multiple of 4 characters.

Interestingly, your data contains no plus signs. I suspect it once contained them but they have probably been replaced with spaces somewhere in transmission. If you replace all spaces with plus signs, the Base64 data is valid and the decoded data will have a length of 256 bytes: 344 characters / 4 * 3 - 2 padding characters.

I further suspect that the Base64 data was used in a URL without proper URL encoding. That's a probable cause for the missing plus signs. Note that Base64 encoded data is not URL safe. Both the plus and the equal signs need to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I think lack of URL encoding is the cause. I looked back at my code again and I set the content type to x-www-form-urlencoded but I forgot to explicitly url encode the data.

Comment: I confirmed that was the issue. I suppose the SUN/Apache decoders ultimately handle incorrectly formatted data differently. Regardless, your answer helped me solve the root of the problem. Thanks a lot.